# Inserting records into a database in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Ok, Im trying to insert some records in the database by creating a command and then using insert like in the documentation I found, but I get error "class app\commands Yii" not found. Now I have this at the top of my controller

```
namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
```

And this is the command i built

```
//added game to database
    foreach ($games as $g) 
    {
        //echo $g[0].'<br>'.$g[1].'<br>'.$g[2].'<br>'.$g[3].'<br>'.$g[4].'<br>'.$g[5].'<br><br>';
        //take the upper and put into database
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();

        $command->insert('nfl_lines',array('away'=>$g[0],'home'=>$g[1]));

    }
```

Comment: In this case, it's unusual to run db commands directly. The point of using a framework is to create a "model", set its attributes and then use its `save()` method to write it to db.

Comment: I'm familiar, but this is a cron job to add records from an xml file. It was way easier to do it this way put it all on one page

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure ActiveRecord doesn't support batch inserts. If you're using db commands anyway, consider `batchInsert()`, it may be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace app\commands;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
```

And

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand();
```

You are using yii2, something different from yii1